# Ctrl + U shortkey of IntelliJ idea equivalent in MyEclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea, myeclipse

I do used *IntelliJ IDEA* as my development environment at past and I have recently started to use *MyEclipse*.

In *IntelliJ*, using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> shortcut on override/implement method go to original method in super class.

Does *MyEclipse* have similar shortcut and if it does how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MyEclipse has the same menu command as standard Eclipse, the equivalent command is *Open Super Implementation* on the Navigate menu. It doesn't have a keyboard shortcut assigned by default, but you can add one.

Comment: Thank for your answer but I guess maybe exist a default short key.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by pressing ***Ctrl+ mouse over*** the method it will show drop down list and in that it has open super implementation. And you can also set your customize key from ***Help --> key assist*** menu..